# Don't want to clear records on form

Tags: ms-access-2013

My Access form is for data entry of donations at my church.  I don't want the form to clear for each new record.  Some of the data will remain the same.  Just want to change some fields and select "Add New Record"

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

1. Go to your form.
2. Switch to `Design view`
3. Select the desired control
4. Switch to the control's `Event` tab
5. In `After Update` Sleect the `...` (3 dots) and choose `Code Builder`
6. Change the method to look like this :

   `Private Sub Name_AfterUpdate()
           Me!Name.DefaultValue = """" & Me!Name.Value & """"
   End Sub`

   My control in this code is `Name`, change that to your control's name
7. Close the code builder
8. Done!

You will have to do this for every field you want not to clear!